# How to write content of div to start of a file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the function xy that writes php to the document:

**go.php**

```
<?php
$file_data = '?';
$file_data .= file_get_contents('xml.xml');
file_put_contents('xml.xml', $file_data);
?>
")}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="content"contenteditable>
  <contenttag>hello</contenttag>
  <logo>hi</logo>
  </div>
```

I would like the content of the `#content` to be written to the start of XML.xml

Note: I could not find a clear answer on Google

Comment: why have you tagged js?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The two best options for dealing with XML data are [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php) and [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).  In either case you can use an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) query to target particular elements.  Eg:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load("xml.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "*/div[@id='content']"\;
$elements = $xpath->query($query);

foreach($elements as $el) {
    // $el->nodeValue 
}
```

Comment: I prefer `DOMDocument` parser http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @odedta Did you read my example?  I show how to do it with DOMDocument :)

Comment: Of course I did, however, you mentioned both XML parsers and I wanted to let the OP know that he is better off using `DOMDocument` parser in my opinion, sorry for being unclear, your answer is perfect.